# The executable file i created for pygame program is not working

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, pyinstaller

I am using pygame to create a traverse drawing program.
the program runs just fine when I run it from command line.
then after compiling it using pyinstaller and running the exe file it shows blank screen and terminates.

As I found in some online forums, I tried importing `pygame._view` in my program but that did not work either.

```py
import sys, pygame
from pygame.locals import*

 running = True
 win_size = [800,650]
 Color_screen=[201, 169, 167]
        Color_line=(0,0,0)

 # initialize pygame
 pygame.init()
 scr = pygame.display.set_mode(win_size)
 pygame.display.set_caption('Traverse')
 scr.fill(Color_screen)
 pygame.display.flip()

 # Drawing Traverse
 for i in range(len(x)-1):
      pygame.time.delay(1000)
      pygame.draw.line(scr,Color_line,(x[i],y[i]),(x[i+1],y[i+1]),2)
      pygame.draw.circle(scr,Color_line,(x[i],y[i]),5,1)
      pygame.draw.circle(scr,Color_line,(x[i],y[i]),10,1)
      font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 16)
      text = font.render(f'M{i+1}', True, Color_line)
      textRect = text.get_rect()
      textRect.center = (20, 20)
      scr.blit(text,[x[i]-30,y[i]-30])
      pygame.display.flip()

 # Displaying Scale
 font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 32)
 text = font.render(f'Scale : {scale} pixels = 1 metre', True, Color_line)  
 textRect = text.get_rect()
 textRect.center = (100, 50)
 scr.blit(text,[100,20])
 pygame.display.flip()
 while running:
   # looking for events
      for events in pygame.event.get():
           if events.type == QUIT:
               running = False
               pygame.quit()
```

The following error message is shown during compilation:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32com'

Comment: The error message is printed but the exe file is still generated ?

Comment: yes. above code is a part of a project. the exe file is created and works fine for other features .just the pygame part doesnot work

Answer (score 0):

`win32com` is located inside the [pywin32](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/) package, assuming you're using windows, you can open cmd with admin rights and enter the following commands:

```sh
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install pywin32
```

and if it still prints the error message:

```sh
pip install pypiwin32
```